How to "remove" 'extensionHost.js:155' from vscode debug terminal?
Can anyone help me get rid of the 'extensionHost.js:155' text that is printed for every line in the debug terminal?
Image from debug terminal
Thx :)
I did try various solutions with modifying launch.json. And settings.json in vscode. But with no luck :(
